# href="javascript:Function() how does it work

Tags: javascript

```
<a href="javascript:Function()"> Content</a>
```

like this ,how does Function work?can i intercept it and if i dont use mouse how can trigger it?

Answer (score 6):

It will be triggered when ever the link is "triggered", i.e. on click or when tabbing to it and pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. You can "intercept" it by replacing `Function` with a custom function:

```
var oldFunc = window.YourFunction;
window.YourFunction = function() {
    // do something
    oldFunc(); // call the old function if necessary
    // do more if necessary
}
```

By the way: You shouldn't do this at all. Use `onclick="..."` or even better, register an event via JavaScript. Both cases will also trigger when the link is not actually mouse-clicked but triggered by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

To use onclick, the link should look like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="YourFunction(); return false;">...</a>
```

To register the event in a modern browser (IE before v9 is not a modern browser in case it matters to you):

```
<a href="#" id="whatever">...</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('whatever').addEventListener('click', YourFunction, false);
</script>
```

To keep it short and cross-browser compatible I'd highly suggest you to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
<a href="#" id="whatever">...</a>
<script>
$('#whatever').on('click', YourFunction);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this if you want to use href**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="smfunction()">Content</a>​

<script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function  smfunction(){
        alert("Running");
    }
</script>
```